# How to get audio capture permission in chrome extension without actual recording

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, getusermedia

I'm using the getUserMedia to record audio from user as follow:

```
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
```

Once this line gets executed it prompts for user audio recording permission. I want to do this step ahead like asking for permission first and if the permission is not granted, I don't show the recording user interface. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

In ordinary web page code it works to get the stream then stop its tracks. A function like this should do it for you.

```
async function getUserMediaPermission (constraints) {
    try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia (constraints)
        if (stream) {
            stream.tracks.forEach(track => track.stop())
            return true
        }
        return false
    } 
    catch(error) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Then you call the function with code like this

```
 const permissionGranted = getUserMediaPermission ({audio:true})
 if (!permissionGranted) console.log ('Hey! to use this you must grant permission!')
```

What this does: it gets a stream. `await getUserMedia()` doesn't complete until the user has granted permission. The `catch{}` is invoked if the user denies permission.

But, on desktop browsers permission is persistent so it it has already been granted `await getUserMedia()` completes right away. The same is true if it has already been denied.

Once you have the stream you must close it. There's no `stream.close()` function: the way you "close" a stream is to stop all its tracks and let the `stream` object go out of scope.

I don't know if this works within Web Extensions; I do know it works on desktop and mobile browsers.  **If you get it working in your Web Extension please post a comment or an answer saying how you did it.**